# SwiftUI keyboard-shortcut without modifier doesn't work in popover

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts

In a View with a textfield I have a popover, activated by a button.
In that popover I want to listen to a keyboardShortcut without modifiers.
These keypresses arrive in the textfild of the parent view instead of the popover.
What can I do, to react on these in the popover?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State var showPopOver = false
  @State var text = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      TextField("enter text here", text: $text)
      Button("show popover"){ showPopOver = true }
      .popover(isPresented: $showPopOver) {PopOverView(text: $text)}      }
    .keyboardShortcut("p")
    .padding()
  }
}

struct PopOverView: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  @Binding var text: String
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text("my Popover")
      Button("set Tom"){
        text = "Tom"
        dismiss()
      }
      .keyboardShortcut("t",modifiers: [])
      //.keyboardShortcut("t") // like this it works
      Button("set Frank"){
        text = "Frank"
        dismiss()
      }
      .keyboardShortcut("f",modifiers: [])
    }
    .padding()
  }
}
```

KeyboardShortcuts with a modifier in the popover do work (commented out).

Comment: You are talking not about "key shortcuts" (which are always with modifiers), but about "key events", but key events are also passed to focused view. In your case TextField is in focus so all key events are passed there. Irrelative of how to intercept key events you need to rethink your app design, because it cannot be more then one focused views. And actually it is not native Apple-platform behavior to have key on buttons, do you have Windows background?

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, I tried to set the Focus to the Button in the popover with the .focus Modifier, but that had no effect. How else can I remove the focus from the textfield?

Comment: It works, if I disable the textfield with .disabled.  I'm wondering, if there is a better way to archive that.

Comment: On which platform do you test? It works on macOS here.

Comment: On macOS. Disabling the textfield worked, setting the focus to the Button did not. Maybe I didn't do it correctly.